# Can a dog be left alone during work hours?

Tags: dogs, psychology

Since I was a kid I've always wanted a dog, and since now I have my own home, I can.

Before thinking about anything else I wanted to find out of it is detrimental to either a dogs physical or mental health to be left at home during office hours?

The hours no one would be home would be 08:30 - 16:00.

If it isn't a responsible thing to do I will have to wait until I retire.

Answer (score 6):

No worries there, just keep him/her busy :)

- Give your dog lots of toys to have fun with during the day, I'm a big fan of foraging toys (make them work for their food).
- Have a good 1 hour run in the morning before work to tucker him/her out for the better part of the day.
- Turn on radio/tv for some background noise.

Doggy daycare is also a good option (though do your research), you can also hire someone to walk your dog at lunch time as well.

If you're worried about your pooch being lonely you can always get two but that's a handful. If this is your first time owning a dog it would be better if you just got one.

Comment: The only issue that would remain would be training, but that's depending if you get a puppy or an adult dog.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a fenced yard that the dog can stay in while you're at work, it should not be a problem. But consider getting two dogs, so that they can keep each other company. Also, consider adopting an adult dog(s) from a shelter, as a puppy would be more likely to get lonely.

If you don't have a yard, then there's the question of how the dog will get a chance to pee or poop. You don't say where you're located, but it's likely you could find someone to walk your dog once a day while you're at work. Alternatively, there may be "doggy day care" centres.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have a well fenced medium sized garden, so that is a possibility. I am in the UK and would rescue rather than fund a breeder. Are there any breeds that would do better in this situation?

Comment: Good to hear that you're planning on adopting a rescue. While there are differences between breeds in terms of how well they would do to be alone part of the day, a lot depends on the individual dog. I recommend that you talk to the shelter about what you're looking for in a dog and what your circumstances are. A good shelter will help match you up with the dog that's right for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have always had a desire to get a dog, but your main concern is time left alone while at work, I would not be concerned. Dogs really don't register time like we do. And will more than likely keep himself entertained or sleep through it.  When you come home it will be as though you just left and came back. The previous recommendation on installing a [doggy door](http://www.carpetrenovations.com/blog/pet-stains-odors-products-blog/how-effective-is-a-doggy-door) is a great idea, so the pet can go in and out to relieve himself and find a butterfly or two or possibly a neighbor next door to bark at.

[image]